# Why is the SpriteRenderer color not updating at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a `GameObject` with a `SpriteRenderer` and its default color is set to white. At runtime I'm setting the color to `Color.gray` and for some reason it is not updating at runtime to the new `gray` tint. I have confirmed that the objects in my script are correct because the sprite completely disappears if I set `enabled` to false and if I have the object selected in the editor and play, the color changes in the `Inspector` but does not update in the `Game View`.

This is my simple script

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer Player1;
    public SpriteRenderer Player2;

    public void SetTurn(bool isPlayer1)
    {
        this.Player1.color = Color.gray;
        this.Player2.color = Color.gray;

        if (isPlayer1)
            this.Player1.color = Color.white;
        else
            this.Player2.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

`SetTurn` is being called from a different script in its `Update` on a mouse click; I have verified that the function is actually running. I've also tried simplifying this to:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer Player1;
    public SpriteRenderer Player2;

    private void Update()
    {
        this.Player1.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

That doesn't even work. There are no warnings and no errors in the console either. I've tried rebooting, rebuilding, quitting and restarting, running on a different machine and running on a completely different platform... nothing works.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Again, the color changes in the `Inspector` at runtime but does not in the `Game View`. Also, if I change the color manually in the `Inspector` at runtime the `Game View` does change color, it just refuses to do it from the script.

**EDIT**

I've also tried using `Color32` just to cover my bases and that doesn't work, as I expected it wouldn't.

**UPDATE**

I completely removed the script and made a new script that I attached directly to the `GameObject` itself and that doesn't even work.

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer m_Renderer;

    void Start()
    {
        this.m_Renderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        this.m_Renderer.color = Color.black;
        Debug.Log("COLOR BLACK");
    }
}
```

The console displays "COLOR BLACK" so I know the Update is being called but still no color change in `Game View` or `Scene View` but it does change in the `Inspector`

**UPDATE 2**

I narrowed it down but still haven't solved it. I'm using the 2d experimental build `5.5.0a6`. I installed the current stable version `5.4.2f2` and the problem does not exist! So, the problem has something to do with the `SpriteRenderer` in version `5.5.0a6`. I'm trying to find out what the issue is, and I hope this gets fixed soon.

**UPDATE 3**
Here is a link to 2 simple projects that illustrate the issue. One for version 5.5.0a6 which DOES contain the issue and the exact same project for version 5.4.2f2 which DOES NOT contain the issue.

[Sample Projects](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By5d2e2jSbmJdjQ5eWFpOXE2bzA)

Comment: Have you tried to disable the renderer and enable it right after (after changing the color) ?

Comment: @Hellium Just tried it and it still doesn't work. I tried disabling then making the change then enabling and also making the change then disabling and enabling again immediately.

Comment: what material/shader are you using on sprite ? You can try to do Player1.color = new Color (1f,0f,0f,1f);

Comment: @Demon the `Sprites-Default` material. Again, this works perfectly fine in the editor using the inspector at runtime so I don't think the material would be the issue, I've also tried every other available material provided by unity itself and those don't work either. Doing `new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)` changes it in the inspector but not the game view, same as everything else I've tried.

Comment: any animations attached? maybe changing the color in the animation

Comment: @Bijan No animator attached but I will try this as a workaround first thing tomorrow. Unfortunately this looks like a bug in the 2D experimental build since it does not exist in the stable build. I wish they would release the 9 slice sprite capabilities soon.

Comment: also try material.color

Comment: Hey can you create a simple project for this problem and share it? I want to take a look at it.

Comment: @Programmer I added a link to a zip file containing 2 projects for 2 different version of Unity. One with the issue and one without, both projects are identical.

Comment: @Bijan I tried `material.color` and I also tried `material.SetColor("_Color", xxx)` but they both do not work.

Comment: Ok. Which one is with the issue and which one is not?

Comment: @Programmer The update says which is which but for clarity `test 5.5.0a6` DOES have the problem and `test 5.4.2f2` DOES NOT.

Comment: Ok I tried  5.5.0a6 but it did not work because I have 5.4.xx.  I get "Failed to load 'Assets/test.unity' because its serialized file version is higher than what this version of Unity supports." error. Is this version made wirh 5.5xxx? If so,sorry I cannot help because I don;t have that version. My suggestion is for you to create create a new project and new script. That script should work fine. Otherwise, it is a bug.

Comment: @Programmer yeah, the 5.5.0a6 one was made with version 5.5.0a6 and the 5.4.2f2 one was made with 5.4.2f2; I thought that was clear. It is a bug and I've filed a bug report with Unity. You won't be able to duplicate the problem unless you install 5.5.0a6 and if you want to compare it you can open the 5.4.2f2 one with your 5.4 version.

Comment: Just realized that 5.5.0a6 is an Unity 2D Experimental Preview Release 2. Oh well, keep us updated if you hear anything from Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Just update for someone who may want the answer to this question. 
In version 2019.1.12f1 of Unity. We have to set 1 more Alpha value after we select the color in the Editor

[Click to see how to set Alpha value after select color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OOYl.jpg)
Then we can use the code normally like:

```
public Color pink;
public Color purple;
void SetRandomColor() {
        int ran = Random.Range(0, 1);
        Debug.Log("RANDOM: " + ran);
        switch (ran) {
            case 0:
                sr.color = pink;
                break;
            case 1:
                sr.color = purple;
                break;
        }
    }
```